# Adding header to docx file using Java and Docx4j library

Tags: java, docx4j

I have 3 files:

1. contentFile
2. footerFile
3. headerFile

All of them are `.docx` files.

Using `docx4j`, how can I add content of the `headerFile` as a header to the pages of `contentFile`. I have to do the same with the `footerFile`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Hint: have a look at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/HeaderFooterCreate.java and the other Header* samples in that dir.